# Making a register from DFFs without using multiplexers

Tags: digital-logic, clock, multiplexer, latch, register

I am currently trying to design a 4-bit register that is optimised in terms of transistor count, since I will be laying it out in a larger circuit that is very limited in terms of chip space. My current design is below.

[image]

I am wondering whether that instead of having a multiplexer for each DFF, I could pass the load signal and clock signal through an and gate and just have that go into the clock signals of all the DFFs. I feel like this should work but its something I have never come across and so that seems odd.

Comment: 1) don't write: "clock signal through an and gate", but write: "clock signal through an AND gate" as that will make it **a lot** easier to read. 2) if you draw the logic table (just the part you want to change) of this and your AND gate solution, is the behavior the same? 3) you're working in a simulator so **make a copy / backup** of the design and do the change and see what happens. 4) If we all never did something because "we haven't seen that before" then new things would never be invented!

Comment: "gated clock" circuits are a thing. But be aware they can easily have timing issues that (once you make them reliable) hobble the performance of synchronous circuits. You didn't say speed was an issue; if not, then look into them more deeply. (They have been deprecated since about the late 1990s at least, for that reason)

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about using a "gated clock". It can work under certain circumstances.

If you are doing this as a CMOS VLSI design remember that you will actually be using a NAND gate plus inverter.

The potential problem is that the NAND and inverter will delay the arrival of the clock at the flip-flops. This can cause hold time problems for the flip-flops themselves. It also means that changes in the flip-flop outputs will be a bit delayed, which can cause setup time problems for the downstream flip-flops.

Comment: In my application I am only running it at 200Hz, and it is a relatively simple circuit with about 2000 MOSFETs in total with a TSMC180nm lithography, so I would assume that the timing issues will not be an issue in m case.

Comment: That would be a poor assumption. Hold-time errors can occur at low frequencies.